# Query on large table using DateTime WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, large-data

I'm attempting to query data from a rather large table, approximately 98 million rows, using datetime columns in the WHERE clause. It takes approximately 12 minutes to complete - which is obviously not acceptable. The query is simple:

```
SELECT ID, DateTime1, DateTime2, Value1, Value2
FROM dataTable
WHERE DateTime1 >= '2017-05-15 09:00' AND
      DateTime1 <= '2017-05-15 09:30'
```

The table has the following structure:

```
Column Name | DataType
-------------------------
ID          | float
DateTime1   | datetime
DateTime2   | datetime
Value1      | float
Value2      | varchar(20)
```

The table has the following index:

```
Nonclustered: DateTime1, DateTime2, ID, Value2
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  You should also put `Value1` into the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server:

Your index does not cover `Value1`, so it has to retrieve that column from the table for each row if it is using your existing index.

You could create an covering index (includes all columns required by the query) like so:

```
create nonclustered index ix_dataTable_DateTime1_cover 
  on dbo.dataTable (DateTime1)
    include (Id, DateTime2, Value1, Value2);
```

or modify your existing index to include `Value1`.

Also, check the execution plan. If still have performance issues, share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at changing the index / adding a new one and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You only have DateTime1 in your where, so make an index only for this column.
A complex index is like putting a string together from all its parts like your DateTime1+DateTime2+ID+Value2. Oh yes, that must be slow.